# Работа с памятью C++ (new, delete)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки, память

Простейший вопрос. Есть следующий код:

```
char* name = new char[10];
name = "Name\0";
delete[] name;
```

Простейший пример, который вроде бы должен работать. Однако программа просто падает без сообщений об ошибках. Отладчик после попытки выполнения последней строчки выдает следующее:

> Source information is missing from the debug information for this
>   module

Что посоветуете? VS17, Win10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте разберем...

```
char* name = new char[10];
```

Выделили память, сохранили адрес в `name`

```
name = "Name\0";
```

Выбросили этот адрес, заменили на адрес строки "Name\0" (кстати, еще один нолик добавит компилятор - к строковому литералу) где-то в сегменте данных.

```
delete[] name;
```

Пробуем удалить память в сегменте данных, где лежит строка... Правда, ничего удивительного, что это не получается? :)

Надо строку *скопировать* в выделенную память.

```
char* name = new char[10];
strcpy(name, "Name");
delete[] name;
```

Ну, или - предваряя ваш вопрос -

```
char* name = new char[10];
strcpy_s(name, 10, "Name");
delete[] name;
```